# How can I strongly-type in what my View inherits from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'UTEPSA' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Here is the view code that's trying to inherit:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UTEPSA.Helpers.PaginatedList<Area>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                IDJefe
            </th>
            <th>
                Nombre
            </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID })%> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.ID %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.IDJefe %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Nombre %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>

    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

And a screenshot of my solution:

How can I correctly reference my PaginatedList? Since the view is inheriting from my thing I want, I'd expect to have strongly typed Model to work with. But intellisense isn't working so somethings wrong.

Comment: You have the correct code, there must be something wrong with how your referencing your PaginatedList. Make sure all your namespaces are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the assembly to both the Project Reference list as well as the `<system.web><compilation><assemblies>` section of web.config.